# How do I implement inter-window DND(drag and drop) functionality in the jetpack compose desktop? Like in Chrome browser

Tags: kotlin

I know I can use Swing and AWT with Jetpack compose desktop to try to implement it, but I have never worked with them and want to use Jetpack compose elements only (design of tabs).
Could you help me at least find some ideas for it?

I also found a [library](https://github.com/MohamedRejeb/compose-dnd) that adds a drag-and-drop feature but it seems to only work within one window. For several windows, it seems I need to use Swing's DropTarget.